# Is it possible to get `event` param from `onsubmit` handler of `form` element?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<form method="post" id="fm1" onsubmit="usernamePasswordLogin();">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

```js
function usernamePasswordLogin(x) {
    // x.preventDefault()
    console.log('x', x)
}
```

when I click SUBMIT button

`usernamePasswordLogin` always logs 'x undefined'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is undefined because you're not passing the event parameter to `usernamePasswordLogin()` when called. You have to pass in the event parameter for `x` to be defined. Try this

```js
function usernamePasswordLogin(x) {
    x.preventDefault()
    console.log('x', x)
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="fm1" onsubmit="usernamePasswordLogin(event);">
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, first time I know the param should be exactly `event`